# Pandas Dataframe data are same or new?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, Pandas dataframes are used : 
 dataframe_1 :

```
     id
0  AB17
1  AB18
2  AB19
3  AB20
4  AB10
```

dataframe_2 :

```
     id
0  AB20
1  AB10
2  AB17
3  AB21
4  AB09
```

Here, dataframe_2 contains **AB20**, **AB10** and **AB17** same as dataframe_1 in random order.
How to check which elements in dataframe_2 **are new and which are same** as dataframe_1 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask and filter by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), if necessary convert output `Series` to `list`:

```
mask = dataframe_2['id'].isin(dataframe_1['id'])
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

same = dataframe_2.loc[mask, 'id'].tolist()
diff = dataframe_2.loc[~mask, 'id'].tolist()

#if want unique values
#same = dataframe_2.loc[mask, 'id'].unique().tolist()
#diff = dataframe_2.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique().tolist()

print (same)
['AB20', 'AB10', 'AB17']

print (diff)
['AB21', 'AB09']
```

Comment: @ShrutiBhutaiya - I only ask if some problem, because remove accepting ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) as:

```
df2.id.isin(df1.id)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: id, dtype: bool
```